# Routing between two wireless interfaces - Linux

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, iptables

Basically, my network looks like that

```
                            +------+
  10.0.0.10 ------ 10.0.0.1=|Laptop|=11.0.0.11 ------ 11.0.0.1 
(wlan0,client)    (AP,wlan0)+------+(wlan1,client)        (AP)
```

wlan0 and wlan1 are usb Wi-Fi adapters connected to laptop

I want to connect these networks via my Laptop, at first I've tried bridging, but it turned out, that bridging is not supported

I've tried this but it didn't worked.

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o wlan1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan1 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan1 -j MASQUERADE
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: you probably don't want to use Masquerade configuration. that is for a NAT configuration, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: all you should really need to do is set routes between the networks, out the particular gateway interface, enable ip forwarding on the nic, and allow the traffic through the firewall.  you likely got the NAT configuration from a tutorial on using linux as an Internet gateway router, not a router in the middle of a network. you will probably need to remove the NAT configuration, but the top two iptables commands look right. can you show us `ip route show`, and let us know which IP ranges you are routing between?

Comment: Your use of `11.0.0.0` network is incorrect. You aren't permitted to use it, it is allocated to US DoD. Just choose another RFC1918 network out there.

Comment: I'm using `11.0.0.0` in my home network and my own devices, I've picked it just because it is fast to type. Anyways I'll change it after I finish with configuring, thx

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two masqeurading rules. You need only to masquerade a client, who has your computer as a default route; you apply source-NAT to packets leaving interface at the "WAN" side.

If firewall is in the default state, you only need this single rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan1 -j MASQUERADE
```

If MTU on different networks differ, you might need to apply MSS fix:

```
iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu
```

(this helps to solve a problem like "ping works, web sites don't" or "some sites work, others don't").

There is extremly common catch. I do this for something like 20 years, and still often forget about this until it is all should work but somewhat isn't working. You need to explicitely enable packet forwarding in the kernel:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

and set the same variable into `/etc/sysctl.conf` for it to be enabled after booting.

Comment: Actually, I don't need access to the Internet. I just want to connect 10.0.0.0/24 and 11.0.0.0/24. I've pinged all the things:
ping 10.0.0.10 -> 11.0.0.11 works
ping 11.0.0.11 -> 10.0.0.10 doesn't

Comment: This doesn't matter, the suggested solution still apply. You may filter internet with additional filtering rule, like `iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.0.0.0/24 -o wlan1 ! -d 11.0.0.0/24 -j REJECT`. By the way, your use of `11.0.0.0` network is incorrect. Don't do that.

Comment: ping 10.0.0.1 -> 11.0.0.11 doen't work

Comment: how exactly did you do this ping?

Comment: `10.0.0.1 (wlan0, AP)` and `11.0.0.11 (wlan1, Client)` are wi-fi adapters connected to USB ports on my laptop. 

`10.0.0.10` is an Android phone connected to `10.0.0.1 (wlan0)`, I've used ping tool from play market. 

`11.0.0.11` is a wi-fi adapter connected to `11.0.0.1 (wlan1)` and to USB port on my laptop. 

`ping 10.0.0.10 -> 11.0.0.11 or 11.0.0.1` work fine. 

For pinging from for example `10.0.0.1` to `11.0.0.11` I've used `ping -I wlan0 11.0.0.11`

Comment: In short, with that command you dind't just "ping from 10.0.0.1". It preselects an interface, then uses its "route hint" to set source IP (which must be 10.0.0.1, but you didn't showed your routing table, so I can't say for sure). Anyway, obviously 11.0.0.11 can't be reached via wlan0, so your command couldn't possibly work. Use e.g. `ping -I 10.0.0.1 11.0.0.11`. Also, this ping is "machine from itself", is a corner case and isn't very useful. Do check from other machine in 10.0.0.0 network.